# What is the easiest way to display the gravatar for an email address

Tags: discussion, gravatar

I noticed that I can change my stackoverflow gravatar by modifying my email address;

With gmail, the address gmailuser+foobar@gmail.com is delivered to gmailuser@gmail.com

By adding +foo I also get a new gravatar from stackoverflow.

So, I'm looking for a "nice looking" one to use.

Is there an easy website that will display a gravatar given an email address?

Comment: Why the heck was this migrated from stackoverflow to meta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Based on http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/gravatar.htm but with corrected code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Gravatar Client Display</TITLE> 
  <script src="MD5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
   function getIt()
   {
    var base = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/";
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value; 
    var hash = MD5(email);
    var fullUrl = base+hash +"?d=identicon&s=128";
    document.getElementById("avatar").src=fullUrl;
    document.getElementById("avatar").style.display="block";

   }
  </script>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>  
 Enter Email for Gravatar:
  <input type="text" id="email" />
  <input type="button" value="Show Gravatar" onclick="getIt();"/>
  <img id="avatar" src="" style="display:none">
 </BODY>
</HTML>

MD5.JS
var MD5 = function (string) {

    function RotateLeft(lValue, iShiftBits) {
        return (lValue<<iShiftBits) | (lValue>>>(32-iShiftBits));
    }

    function AddUnsigned(lX,lY) {
        var lX4,lY4,lX8,lY8,lResult;
        lX8 = (lX & 0x80000000);
        lY8 = (lY & 0x80000000);
        lX4 = (lX & 0x40000000);
        lY4 = (lY & 0x40000000);
        lResult = (lX & 0x3FFFFFFF)+(lY & 0x3FFFFFFF);
        if (lX4 & lY4) {
            return (lResult ^ 0x80000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
        }
        if (lX4 | lY4) {
            if (lResult & 0x40000000) {
                return (lResult ^ 0xC0000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
            } else {
                return (lResult ^ 0x40000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
            }
        } else {
            return (lResult ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
        }
    }

    function F(x,y,z) { return (x & y) | ((~x) & z); }
    function G(x,y,z) { return (x & z) | (y & (~z)); }
    function H(x,y,z) { return (x ^ y ^ z); }
    function I(x,y,z) { return (y ^ (x | (~z))); }

    function FF(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
        a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(F(b, c, d), x), ac));
        return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
    };

    function GG(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
        a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(G(b, c, d), x), ac));
        return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
    };

    function HH(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
        a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(H(b, c, d), x), ac));
        return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
    };

    function II(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
        a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(I(b, c, d), x), ac));
        return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
    };

    function ConvertToWordArray(string) {
        var lWordCount;
        var lMessageLength = string.length;
        var lNumberOfWords_temp1=lMessageLength + 8;
        var lNumberOfWords_temp2=(lNumberOfWords_temp1-(lNumberOfWords_temp1 % 64))/64;
        var lNumberOfWords = (lNumberOfWords_temp2+1)*16;
        var lWordArray=Array(lNumberOfWords-1);
        var lBytePosition = 0;
        var lByteCount = 0;
        while ( lByteCount < lMessageLength ) {
            lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
            lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
            lWordArray[lWordCount] = (lWordArray[lWordCount] | (string.charCodeAt(lByteCount)<<lBytePosition));
            lByteCount++;
        }
        lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
        lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
        lWordArray[lWordCount] = lWordArray[lWordCount] | (0x80<<lBytePosition);
        lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-2] = lMessageLength<<3;
        lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-1] = lMessageLength>>>29;
        return lWordArray;
    };

    function WordToHex(lValue) {
        var WordToHexValue="",WordToHexValue_temp="",lByte,lCount;
        for (lCount = 0;lCount<=3;lCount++) {
            lByte = (lValue>>>(lCount*8)) & 255;
            WordToHexValue_temp = "0" + lByte.toString(16);
            WordToHexValue = WordToHexValue + WordToHexValue_temp.substr(WordToHexValue_temp.length-2,2);
        }
        return WordToHexValue;
    };

    function Utf8Encode(string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
        var utftext = "";

        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }

        }

        return utftext;
    };

    var x=Array();
    var k,AA,BB,CC,DD,a,b,c,d;
    var S11=7, S12=12, S13=17, S14=22;
    var S21=5, S22=9 , S23=14, S24=20;
    var S31=4, S32=11, S33=16, S34=23;
    var S41=6, S42=10, S43=15, S44=21;

    string = Utf8Encode(string);

    x = ConvertToWordArray(string);

    a = 0x67452301; b = 0xEFCDAB89; c = 0x98BADCFE; d = 0x10325476;

    for (k=0;k<x.length;k+=16) {
        AA=a; BB=b; CC=c; DD=d;
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S11,0xD76AA478);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+1], S12,0xE8C7B756);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S13,0x242070DB);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+3], S14,0xC1BDCEEE);
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S11,0xF57C0FAF);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+5], S12,0x4787C62A);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S13,0xA8304613);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+7], S14,0xFD469501);
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S11,0x698098D8);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+9], S12,0x8B44F7AF);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S13,0xFFFF5BB1);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+11],S14,0x895CD7BE);
        a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S11,0x6B901122);
        d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+13],S12,0xFD987193);
        c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S13,0xA679438E);
        b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+15],S14,0x49B40821);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S21,0xF61E2562);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+6], S22,0xC040B340);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S23,0x265E5A51);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+0], S24,0xE9B6C7AA);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S21,0xD62F105D);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+10],S22,0x2441453);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S23,0xD8A1E681);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+4], S24,0xE7D3FBC8);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S21,0x21E1CDE6);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+14],S22,0xC33707D6);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S23,0xF4D50D87);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+8], S24,0x455A14ED);
        a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S21,0xA9E3E905);
        d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+2], S22,0xFCEFA3F8);
        c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S23,0x676F02D9);
        b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+12],S24,0x8D2A4C8A);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S31,0xFFFA3942);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+8], S32,0x8771F681);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S33,0x6D9D6122);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+14],S34,0xFDE5380C);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S31,0xA4BEEA44);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+4], S32,0x4BDECFA9);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S33,0xF6BB4B60);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+10],S34,0xBEBFBC70);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S31,0x289B7EC6);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+0], S32,0xEAA127FA);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S33,0xD4EF3085);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+6], S34,0x4881D05);
        a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S31,0xD9D4D039);
        d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+12],S32,0xE6DB99E5);
        c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S33,0x1FA27CF8);
        b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+2], S34,0xC4AC5665);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S41,0xF4292244);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+7], S42,0x432AFF97);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S43,0xAB9423A7);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+5], S44,0xFC93A039);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S41,0x655B59C3);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+3], S42,0x8F0CCC92);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S43,0xFFEFF47D);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+1], S44,0x85845DD1);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S41,0x6FA87E4F);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+15],S42,0xFE2CE6E0);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S43,0xA3014314);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+13],S44,0x4E0811A1);
        a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S41,0xF7537E82);
        d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+11],S42,0xBD3AF235);
        c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S43,0x2AD7D2BB);
        b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+9], S44,0xEB86D391);
        a=AddUnsigned(a,AA);
        b=AddUnsigned(b,BB);
        c=AddUnsigned(c,CC);
        d=AddUnsigned(d,DD);
    }

    var temp = WordToHex(a)+WordToHex(b)+WordToHex(c)+WordToHex(d);

    return temp.toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this answer is that it requires the users's email address to be rendered to the client. Part of the point of identicons is to protect the users' private information whilst still uniquely identifying them. Hence the use of an MD5 hash which cannot be reverse engineered. What you've suggested will work but does disclose user's private information.

Comment: True, but the problem was to find a way to preview the identicon for a given email.  So the existing email would be the expected input to such a website anyway

Comment: how to use this to select a good structural avatar

Answer (score 11):

Gravatars are based on the Md5 of your email

So run each email through an MD5 hashing algorithm and insert the resulting MD5 into the a gravatar URL

Here are some examples:

https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d6a2104f846a8165d60b5b14af7f0313?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG

[image]

https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d6a2104f846a8165d50b5b14af7f0313?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG

[image]

https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d6a3104f846a8165d50b5b14af7f0313?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG

[image]

Comment: Is there any site that will automate the MD5 hash and return the gravatar?

Answer (score 6):

Generate your own image, then register it with [gravatar.com](http://gravatar.com/) and use the same email address you always use.

Answer (score 3):

In a linux shell:

```
echo -n "hi" |md5sum
49f68a5c8493ec2c0bf489821c21fc3b  -
```

Then use wget or curl to download a gravatar specific to the md5sum associated to the string hi.

```
http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/49f68a5c8493ec2c0bf489821c21fc3b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG
```

This could be modified to generate md5sum's from say a dictionary of words and then call wget with each hash downloading all the identicons. You could then peruse through the downloaded identicons looking for the one you want, and then upload it back to your gravatar account.

Answer (score 0):

Found this demo page which generates a gravatar for a given String

http://finalboss.org/g/?hash=lol